# scrolling text field help as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6, flash-cc

Currently got text off stage that I would like to come onto the stage and stop at a certain position (97, 233.10) on my stage. I'm a little confused on where to stop it and what code to use?

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mcInfo);

 function mcInfo (e:Event):void {

//check position of logo
//if inside the stage move left to right
//if outside stage reposition

if (info.x<stage.stageWidth) {
    info.x+=30;
    stop();
    } else {
        //reset position
        info.x=-450;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

It also seems that Flash is now returning an output error when I scroll through the rest of my pages:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finaldesign_fla::MainTimeline/mcInfo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if statement we check if the object has exceeded the target position and stop the loop if it has. Otherwise keep incrementing the object's position.

```
targetPosition = {x:97, y:233.10};

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mcInfo);

function mcInfo(e:Event) {
   if (info.x >= targetPosition.x) {
      info.x = targetPosition.x;
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mcInfo);
   } else {
      info.x += 30;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. But how do I get it to stop in that position (97, 233.10)? 
It is still looping with that line of code?

Comment: It seems unnecessary for the line **if (info.x<stage.stageWidth) { }** if the object is going to stop at x=97

Comment: how do i implement that into my code to stop at x=97? still a little stumped.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that info is on stage and try add:

```
if(info != null && stage != null)
```